# How to sign a String with an Android X509Certificate certificate A1

Tags: java, android, x509certificate

Good afternoon folks, I'm new to developing apps for android and after many searches I still can't sign a string with X509Certificate A1 on android. I have the certificate in byte [] and the password, which are returned from a service and I pass as a parameter to the method SubscribeString, but I'm not able to sign. I tried to use the following code:

```java
public String SubscribeString(String texto, byte[] certificateByte, String password)
{
        try {

            InputStream certificado = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateByte);

            KeyStore rep = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            rep.load(certificado, password.toCharArray());
            String alias = "TravelTicket";
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) rep.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
            Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            /* Initializing the object with a private key */
            dsa.initSign(privateKey);

            /* Update and sign the data */
            dsa.update(texto.getBytes());
            byte[] sig = dsa.sign();
            texto = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(sig));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return texto;
}
```

Comment: what error gives you?

Comment: Could it be that "SHA1withRSA" is no longer supported (because it's not considered secure enough)?